# Resize and Reposition Annotation in Core Plot while zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am trying to resize and reposition the text annotation on the graph when the user zooms in and out, and I don't really know where to go from here.

```
- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint {
        NSArray *annotations = space.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.annotations;
        for (id annotation in annotations) {
            if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation class]]) {
                CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *textAnnotation = (CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *)annotation;
                if ([textAnnotation.contentLayer isKindOfClass:[CPTTextLayer class]]) {
                    // I want to resize font and reposition the annotation when the user zooms
                }
            }
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already found the text layer that draws the annotation text. Change the `textStyle` of the text layer to adjust the font size.

The annotation will follow its `anchorPlotPoint` and `displacement` as the plot space changes. You can update those properties if needed to move the annotation relative to its host.

Comment: What do you mean the annotation will follow its anchorPlotPoint and displacement as the plot space changes. What should I update these properties by? For example, I want to enlarge the graph and the interactionScale is > 1, how should I update the anchorPlotPoint and displacement of the text layer. Thanks

Comment: My point was you shouldn't have to change them at all. The whole point of a plot space annotation is that it is fixed to a particular spot in the data coordinates. It will move with the plot as the user zooms and scales the plot. The `anchorPlotPoint` is the fixed data coordinate and the `displacement` is a pixel (point) offset between the `anchorPlotPoint` and the `contentAnchor` of the `contentLayer`.